# How to access the external storage?

Tags: android, storage

I am creating an Android app. I use

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
```

to get the external storage path and create a new file in it. It seems my code can run. But I cannot find the new file it creates. Could you please tell me how can I find the file by computer? Like what is the path of the external storage? Thank you!

Comment: External storage will appear as a removable drive on your computer. The file will be wherever you saved it on the external storage.

Comment: you must give `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission for your application

Comment: I have already give WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. I want to find whether the file has already created or not. But cannot find it on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Please use DDMS, use File Explorer and look in the folder /mnt/sdcard/ should be there

Comment: I am using a emulator for debugging.

Comment: that's it, in Eclipse: Window->Open Perspective -> DDMS -> "File Explorer" tab; you will find your files there under the directory `/mnt/sdcard/`

Comment: @user2141396 the "Window" menu is a menu inside Eclipse, you should see it on top in Eclipse

Comment: Thank you so much. I have seen the file.

Comment: @user2141396 ...well.. if any of these answers helped you you could give back reputation, by accepting an answer (click green tick on the left) and/or upvoting an answer (click orange up arrow on the left). Good luck with your work! maurizio

Answer (score 0):

On most devices this will return /mnt/sdcard or /mnt/sdcard-ext. This will be the root of the disk if you mount the sdcard via USB. If you use adb to pull the files you would use the full /mnt/sdcard/... path.

The strange thing about your question is that you have the value in a string in your code. Generally people would just inspect the string or log its value to the console.